# Rotating rectangle formula

Tags: differential-geometry

A rectangle $0,0-200,150$ is rotating from the top-left corner $(0,0\text{ axis})$
starting from $0$ degrees to a full turn of $360$ degrees.

another rectangle, also $0,0-200,150$ is overlapping the first one and its not rotating.
(that means at $90$ degrees the rotating rectangle will not be overlapped anymore)
both have a center point $(100,75)$, but only at $0$ degrees they have the same $\frac{x}{y}$.

What I need is a formula for $x$ and $y$.

The result should be the difference between the rotating rectangle center point and the non rotating rectangle. So, at any given degree I can calculate the distant between the center points.

Answer (score 1):

$$\pmatrix{x\\y} = \pmatrix{\cos\phi& -\sin\phi\\ \sin\phi &\cos\phi}\cdot \pmatrix{100\\75}$$
$\phi$ is going from the $x$-axis (when $\phi=0^\circ$) towards the $y$-axis (when $\phi=90^\circ$). For the distance you can apply Pythagorean theorem for their subtraction vector:
$$\pmatrix{x\\y}-\pmatrix{100\\75}=\pmatrix{\cos\phi -1& -\sin\phi\\ \sin\phi &\cos\phi-1}\cdot \pmatrix{100\\75}. $$

Comment: thx for the reply. i did find another way to get around the problem. w = width, h = height, radian = 180/pi, x1 = w * cos(rotation / radian) , x2 = h * sin(rotation / radian), y1 = w * sin(rotation / radian), y2 = h * cos(rotation / radian). then lx = x2 + ((w - (x1+x2)) / 2) and ly = (h - y2 - y1) / 2. so, the next rectangle i add lx and ly to the (0,0) to make the rectangle in the center